# SMP 3.0 Sp05 Online Store Issue in Android

Tags: android, smp, sap-smp

I'm getting the following error when trying to fetch the data using OnlineStore in Native Android.

com.sap.dcode.online.services.online.OnlineODataStoreException: com.sap.smp.client.odata.exception.ODataNetworkException: Unknown network response error occured

Answer (score -1):

We have the same problem using sp06 and cockpit odata, but if we use a public odata service like "http://sapes1.sapdevcenter.com:8080/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/" we dont have any problem, in a test we update from sp06 to sp07 and it works the get service but the delete and post doesn't works.